# How to select SHA1 hash values correctly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, encryption, sha1

I need to extract SHA1 Passwords from a Microsoft SQL Server database in order to use them in an external system.

When I do a simple select query for a known password, I get this result (password is "password"):

```
"{SHA1=5b9febc2d7429c8f2002721484a71a84c12730c7}"
```

But it should be `5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8`.

Any idea how to select it to get the expected value `5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8`?

Comment: Please paste your script

Comment: Why can't you just use string functions to do that? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: my problem is not about selecting just the value. my problem is that the hash values are not matching.

Comment: Ah I overlooked that because the first two letters agree :)

Comment: In that case how do you expect an answer with the information that is currently given? How is anyone supposed to figure out why the value in the database does not match what you expect? We don't know what you expect and what was stored in the database.

Comment: SELECT  [Password] FROM [Interfaces].[dbo].[Users]

Comment: @usr I though there is a simple explanation for my problem. I spent hours on researching this without success. I guess it is only a problem of data types. As i am a beginner, maybe this is not the right platform for my question. I am sorry.

Comment: This is a string data type. No other type can store something like `SHA1=`. The value is just stored literally in the database. If it's wrong then it has been stored wrong. No idea where the "right" value comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SHA1 hashing is done on bytes, not on characters, therefore it's important to make sure that the conversion from characters to bytes is done with an agreed upon encoding.

`5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8` is the SHA1 hash of `password` encoded in ASCII/UTF-8.

`5b9febc2d7429c8f2002721484a71a84c12730c7` is the SHA1 hash of `password` encoded in UTF-16-BE.

To fix this, pick one encoding, and change whatever code is using the other encoding to match.